# Single page application (SPA) using web components with Dart not JS

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, core-elements

I'm trying to do a [single page application (SPA) using web components](https://www.polymer-project.org/articles/spa.html#datamodel) as in the linked example. But with Dart instead of javascript. I'd like to put the whole `<core-scaffold>` in a Polymer Element. The layout is working as expected, but when I get to the part "Simplifying the markup using a data model" I can't understand how to bind my dart model equivalent to the javascript model in the example. Should this attribute `<template is="auto-binding">` be in the main template of the Polymer element, or where does that go? Any pointers from you experts?

Edit: OK, I'm adding some code to this question.
In darteditor i started a new project with the option using polymer library selected. In the created main-html-file all I did was remove the "counter"-attribute in `<click-counter>`. I added these dependencies `paper_elements: 0.5.0, polymer: any` I replaced everything in clickcounter.dart with:

```dart
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';
import 'dart:html';

@CustomTag('click-counter')
class ClickCounter extends PolymerElement {
  @observable var route = 0;
  @observable List<dynamic> pages = [
                           {'name': 'Single', 'hash': 'one'}, 
                           {'name': 'page', 'hash': 'two'}, 
                           {'name': 'app', 'hash': 'three'}
                     ];

  ClickCounter.created() : super.created() {
  } 
}
```

And I replaced everything in clickcounter.html with:

```dart
<link rel="import" href="packages/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="packages/core_elements/core_scaffold.html">
<link rel="import" href="packages/core_elements/core_header_panel.html">
<link rel="import" href="packages/core_elements/core_toolbar.html">
<link rel="import" href="packages/core_elements/core_menu.html">
<link rel="import" href="packages/core_elements/core_item.html">
<link rel="import" href="packages/core_elements/core_transition.html">
<link rel="import" href="packages/core_elements/core_animated_pages.html">
<link rel="import" href="packages/core_elements/core_animated_pages/transitions/core_transition_pages.html">

<link rel="import" href="packages/paper_elements/paper_item.html">

<polymer-element name="click-counter">
  <template>
    <style>
    </style>

    <core-scaffold>
      <core-header-panel navigation flex mode="waterfall">
        <core-toolbar>Application</core-toolbar>
        <core-menu theme="core-light-theme" valueattr="hash" selected="{{route}}">
          <template repeat="{{page in pages}}">
            <paper-item icon="settings" label="{{page['name']}}" hash="{{page['hash']}}">
              <a _href="#{{page['hash']}}"></a>
            </paper-item>
          </template>
        </core-menu>
      </core-header-panel>
      <div tool>Title</div>
      <core-animated-pages  selected="{{route}}" transitions="slide-from-right">
        <template repeat="{{page in pages}}">
          <section hash="{{page['hash']}}" layout vertical center-center>
            <div>{{page['name']}}</div>
          </section>
        </template>
      </core-animated-pages>
    </core-scaffold>

  </template>
  <script type="application/dart" src="clickcounter.dart"></script>
</polymer-element>
```

I run in Dartium, and see a fine layout with the three menu options. The main area has the word "single" at startup, as the first menu option is selected. When I click the second menu option I get this error:

```dart
Exception caught during observer callback: TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined
    at core-animated-pages.Polymer.applySelection (http://localhost:8081/spa_test.html:939:15)
    at core-animated-pages.Polymer.selectedItemChanged (http://localhost:8081/spa_test.html:4389:14)
    at core-animated-pages.g.invokeMethod (http://localhost:8081/packages/polymer/src/js/polymer/polymer.js:13:25932)
    at core-animated-pages.g.notifyPropertyChanges (http://localhost:8081/packages/polymer/src/js/polymer/polymer.js:13:24037)
    at Object.x.report_ (http://localhost:8081/packages/polymer/src/js/polymer/polymer.js:12:18274)
    at Object.S.check_ (http://localhost:8081/packages/polymer/src/js/polymer/polymer.js:12:22612)
    at c (http://localhost:8081/packages/polymer/src/js/polymer/polymer.js:12:12181) polymer.concat.js:4861
```

Comment: If I change the initial value of `route` to `one` the exception goes away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put everything in a Polymer element you use this Polymer element **instead** of `<template is="auto-binding">` not in addition to. The model is the class of the Polymer element that contains `<core-scaffold>`.

If you add more code that shows what you try to accomplish it is easier to make concrete suggestions.

#### Update

I changed

```dart
@observable var route = 'one';
```

to get rid of the exception
and added

```dart
routeChanged(oldVal, newVal) {
  print(newVal);
}
```

to see what values are assigned (prints 'one', 'two', 'three').

and also added

```dart
<link rel="import" href="packages/paper_elements/paper_item.html">
```

Comment: I see. Now I changed to: @observable var route = '0'; and ...{'name': 'Single', 'hash': '0'}... Then the main area gets it's content right, and I can change with the menu. Without animation though.

Comment: I haven't used these elements yet myself. I don't know why the added transition doesn't work. I don't have time today to take another look. Maybe tomorrow.

Comment: Well, the main issue was that I didn't think about that a Polymer element is a template + code. The animation is just "sprinkle". Thank you for your effort.

Comment: Back to this after a few days...
I can't make it work with other strings than '0', '1' for hash. Can you? I see in the comments in 'core-selector.html' in core packages: "If you want a specific attribute value of the element to be used instead of index, set "valueattr" to that attribute name."